# Connecting ASP.NET MVC2 App to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, asp.net-mvc-2

So I have a database running in SQL Server Management Studio.

The server information in the top of the Object Explorer says this:

(local)(SQL Server 10.0.2531 - Scott-PC\Scott)

How do I connect my ASP.NET MVC2 App to this instance. I want a connection string in the web.config and then I want to be able to have a Database.cs class that performs all the stored proc and queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data Source=Scott-PC;Initial Catalog=DatabseName;User Id=Scott;Password=password;
```

check [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008) for other options

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample...

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ProductionServerEntities"
      connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.csdl|res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.MyDBEntityModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSQLSERVER;attachdbfilename=C:\inetpub\domains\MyDomainName\App_Data\MyDB03.mdf;Database=MyDB06;integrated security=False;User ID=sa;Password=MyPassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"
      providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```